Pillow draw line with gradient color where the color gradually from darkgreen to the lime as y position is increased relatively from starting y point
How to draw line in Pillow, but the color of line is gradually became lighter (from darkgreen) as every dot of line go to the bottom relatively from starting point (y increase)?
I expect there is argument like this:
img = Image.new('RGB', (1024, 800))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

draw.line([(p1x, p1y), (p2x, p2y)], width=2, start_color='darkgreen', end_color='lime', gradient_based_on='+y')


See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63246839/2836621
