# Pillow: How to draw text with the inverse color of the underlying image?

Tags: python, colors, graphics, python-imaging-library

I want to draw text on an `Image` in the inverse color of the background (to make sure the text is readable no matter the background color).

This is what it should look like:

[image]

---

Related:

- [Is there a way, to draw Text with a gradient color with Pillow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53957703/1410221)

Comment: Keep in mind that the inverse color of `#7f7f7f` is `#808080`, which is essentially indistinguishable.

Comment: @MarioWelzig IK, this is a practical matter used with reasonable images.

Comment: What is the "inverse" of a color? Is it an RGB color? What if the background is an image (and not a single color)?

Comment: Might be of interest [How to draw text with image in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297272/how-to-draw-text-with-image-in-background)

Comment: @martineau The inverse needs to be calculated per pixel (each background pixel has a single color which has an inverse).

Comment: You still haven't defined what the inverse of a color is.

Comment: I don't understand. Get the colour of the background, subtract it from 255 and draw your text that colour. Which part are you stuck with?

Comment: @martineau I think the inverse should an XOR of the background color with white, but I know the inverse effect from Photoshop etc, so I am not sure.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The background is a picture, not a single solid color.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you edited your question to show what you are looking for if you can mock it up in Photoshop.

Comment: Draw the text in white on a black background same size as original. Get the coordinates of the white pixels. Invert pixels at those coordinates in original image. Maybe. Untested.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That was my idea as well. Won't anti-aliasing and stuff be a problem? I guess it shouldn't matter much ...

Comment: I don't know yet. You haven't given any indication of the content, size or type of your image, nor what style/font/size of text you plan to use, nor how you expect the result to look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229910/discussion-between-happyface-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: Also, if that was your best idea, you should have shown that as your best attempt at code in your question.

Comment: @PeterO. Yes. I have linked to it as an answer, actually.